# Live-action movie where a boy goes fishing and the fish appear above the lake

Tags: story-identification, movie

The main problem is that I remember this children's film very poorly.

I watched it about 15 years ago.

I clearly remember the moment that the boy went fishing, but there was some kind of magic, and all the fish suddenly appeared above the lake; something like that was there.

I understand that this knowledge is very hard to find, but that’s all I remember. I haven’t gotten this movie out of my head for over 3 years now, and I just can’t find it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You've tagged this both "movie" and "TV;" was it a TV movie or a TV show?  Was it live-action or animated?  Where and when did you see it?

Comment: Hello! it was a movie. children's film, not animated. I watched it about 15 years ago. I don’t know exactly where I saw it

Comment: How the fish looked like above the lake? What they were doing? Was it some kind of a magic trap to make it easy to catch?

Comment: I do not remember exactly. but in my opinion yes! it seemed like it was generally connected with something alien and he wanted to help the boy catch a fish. the fish were in bubbles above the lake. aowovooa

Comment: Sounds a lot more magical than the corresponding moment in the Fargo TV series.

Answer (score 8):

The movie you’re looking for is called [*The Secret of The Magic Gourd*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Secret_of_the_Magic_Gourd_(2007_film)) (2007). I’ve been looking for this movie for many years too and after many attempts I found it today!

> When an inquisitive 11 year old discovers a mythical, magical gourd while fishing, he has no idea of the trouble that lies at the end of his hook. With the ability to grant any and every wish, The Magic Gourd attempts to make all of the boy's dreams come true, but instead succeeds in turning his world upside down.

The fish floating scene is in the trailer below.

Comment: Nice! And welcome to the site.

Answer (score 3):

I'm certain that you remember the recent Netflix series "[Raising Dion](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raising_Dion)", about ordinary people who develop super-powers after a bizarre incident with the Aurora Borealis.

The fish scene was a demonstration of the main character's power. (This character, Dion, is actually the child of one of the affected people, inheriting his father's powers) After levitating the fish, Dion's mother warned him that they would die without water, so Dion levitated water-bubbles for every fish.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to match the OP's description, which is of a movie, and that they watched it about 15 years ago. *Raising Dion* is not a movie, and it was released in 2019.